# bridge LAN and Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge

I have two independent networks one is LAN network over Mikrotik router and another is wifi network over belkin router. Both are having independent internet connection. I want to make bridge between to networks( e.g, server in the LAN would be accessible for Wi-Fi user). How do I do it?

Comment: Based on what you said on the Mikrotik forum, you have two different broadband connections. One connects to the Mikrotik, the other connects to a different router that provides wifi. Both independent networks are behind NAT, and both are using different IP addresses within the same 192.168.2.0/24 address range.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing one of the networks to a different segment, such as changing the Wi-Fi LAN to 192.168.3.0/24, since currently both are on 192.168.2.0/24. Then you can configure a router to be a gateway between the two different LANs. For the 192.168.2.0/24 LAN, some host that is on 192.168.2.0/24 will have to also be connected to 192.168.3.0/24. Say that host is connected to both LANs with the addresses 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.3.2. Every host on 192.168.2.0/24 will have to have 192.168.2.2 added to its routing table as the gateway to get to 192.168.3.0/24, and every host on 192.168.3.0/24 will have to have the same thing done the the other way around so that 192.168.3.2 is the gateway for 192.168.2.0/24. If you just add the routes to the existing routers instead of each host, then all traffic will go to the router and the back out again on to the LAN to the router that's connecting the two segments.

If you can configure the Mikrotik to be the router that connects the two LANs, then you don't have to add routes to all the hosts on the 192.168.2.0/24 LAN. But all the hosts on the 192.168.3.0/24 LAN will need to have the Mikrotik added as a gateway to get to 192.168.2.0/24.

Chances are the DHCP server on the to be 192.168.3.0 WiFi LAN can't be configured to serve out custom routes, so the route to get to the router that's connecting the two LANs will have to be manually added on each host.

Each LAN continues to work with its own broadband connection, but now there is a direct route between the LANs to access each other's private IP address ranges. IF one broadband connection goes down, this will not permit one LAN to access the Internet through the other LAN's broadband connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the MikroTik has 3 ports just plug it into each of the three: Internet, LAN, and WiFi's "LAN" port. Otherwise this sort of setup gets complicated very quickly.

Comment: [check my setup here](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=84671)

Comment: This could get complicated.  You would likely have two DHCP servers at this point.  Internal DNS probably wouldn't work between subnets either.

Comment: You can't just connect two disparate networks together and expect that they will work without addressing things like routes and DHCP. This doesn't even come close to answering the question. This simply states the physical nature of connecting the two, but not the logical problem of allowing connectivity between the two networks for server access.

Comment: @MaQleod You wrote a comment twice a long as my crappy answer explaining why it's crappy instead of writing a good answer... probably for the same reason I didn't write a good answer. =]

Comment: @Jason I don't have DHCP server running in Mikrotik router, I have assigned private IP's manually to all the systems.

Comment: MikroTiks have to have roles assigned to ports, you can't just plug them in and have it work

Comment: @ekaj I know, I was sharply simplifying my response to match the effort put into the Question. Feel free to write a detailed Answer and you've got my upvote...

Comment: @niren Can you add routes on your Belkin router? And can you plug the routers in to each other physically or no?